# Polling Amazon SQS Queue with Ruby

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

The Amazon SDK for Ruby changes frequently, the current version of the `aws-sdk` Ruby gem is [2.0.29](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk). The [old method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/SQS/Queue.html) of polling Amazon SQS messages is no longer valid

```
# polling SQS Queue
queue.poll do |msg|
  puts "Got message: #{msg.body}"
end
```

What is the correct method now for the version 2.0 of the [AWS SDK for Ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby)?

Comment: To be fair, the SDK was major version 1 for ~4 years. While it receives frequent updates, they backwards compatible except when changing major version, such as 1 -> 2.  You can continue using v1 and you can even use both v1 and v2 in the same project.

Comment: Yes. I tried v1 and it worked instantly. Is it deprecated now? Developers hate changing APIs, because they break everything. Facebook used to offer the worst APIs, because they change every few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 2 SDK does not implement queue polling yet. It is on the SDK backlog as a feature request: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/FEATURE_REQUESTS.md#amazon-sqs-queue-poller.

Comment: There is now an open pull-request to added a queue poller to the v2 SDK. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/pull/740

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of the latest Ruby AWS SDK, I do not see a polling method. However, there is a method `receive_message`. The details are at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SQS/Client.html#receive_message-instance_method

Also, you can configure your SQS to always return a message in response. Here are the details http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html

You will need to make sure the connection does not timeout in case you have to wait too long for the message to arrive and be delivered to you.

Lastly, you can mimic the poll method by calling the `receive_message` in a while loop and only breaking out of the loop once the response contains some messages. You can employ recursion to process all the messages in a similar fashion.

**Updated March 12, 2015**

You will also need to delete the message if you want to imitate the poll method.

Comment: You will also need to delete the message after processing if you want to imitate the `#poll` method from the v1 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You may check [Shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken#rails-integration), it's built on top of SQS and also integration with Rails (ActiveJob). But you can also use it without Rails, in a standalone Ruby app.